# Install SSL certificate on IIS which has been removed

Tags: web-services, security, iis, ssl, ssl-certificate

Recently one SSL certificate has been removed from IIS but still available in Trusted Root when I open it via MMC. The cert seems dose not have a private key so when I export it again from mmc it creates a CRE file instead of PFX. Now how I can reinstall again the cert type (*.cer) from trusted root to ISS to make the HTTPS works again. I am not sure I  can access the physical path of the certificates which are in trusted root and add them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it via exporting the cert from MMC and then by selecting "Create Certificate Request..." in IIS. Point to the exported cert file and put the friendly name in the second text box.  But the problem was that IIS could not find the Cert friendly name in Trusted Root just because the length of the friendly name was more than 40! it just prompting that "Cannot find the certificate request associated with this...". So by editing the friendly to max 40 and put the same name when you do Complete Certificate Request will solve the problem.